# Is an if-else calling same function(s) vulnerable to side channel attacks

Tags: implementation, side-channel-attack, timing-attack

If I have a function `f(x, y)` and `g(x, y)` and f and g a are constant time, is the following code vulnerable to side channel attacks (assuming the conditional is constant time as well)

```
if (conditional) {
  f(a, b);
  g(b, a);
else {
  f(b, a);
  g(a, b);
}
```

Comment: [Use special condition on the assignment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/75408/efficient-function-algorithm-method-to-do-modular-exponentiation/75419#75419)

Comment: Also, this is a must to read [How can I understand whether my C implementation is constant-time or not (i.e. resistant to timing attacks)](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/96634/18298)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The `if-else` statements illustrated in the OP would usually compile to something similar to this:

```
JUMP-IF   ElseLabel, Condition-Register;
MOV       Arg1, a
MOV       Arg2, b
CALL      f
MOV       Arg1, b
MOV       Arg2, a
CALL      g
JUMP-TO   EndOfElseLabel
ElseLabel:
MOV       Arg1, b
MOV       Arg2, a
CALL      f
MOV       Arg1, a
MOV       Arg2, b
CALL      g
EndOfElseLabel:
```

It is the consensus of the cryptography community that any non-deterministic code paths constitute side channel, such as the one above where assembly code may take either path depending on the condition. This is exacerbated considering (among many reasons) the CPU implementations would often carry out *predictive* branching - code paths are executed behind-the-scene with outcome chosen at a time deferred to when the condition is actually computed.

Comment: This answer need the solution, though the OP did not show how they used the result..

Comment: @kelalaka I may offer a solution if OP tell us what language they're using. I would assume C, but even then, I need to know what type each variables are.

Comment: We have a common solution for the [if/else](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/63783/18298) independent of the language, the real problem what they do with the result..

Comment: @DannyNiu I'm using Rust for the same. Both results are assigned to an x and y variable in both branches.

Comment: Then you may separate the condition and use 2:1 multiplexer as stated in the [if/else](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/63783/18298)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the code shown is potentially vulnerable to timing attack, the simplest form of side-channel attack, to determine the value of `condition`. More generally, essentially any use of a variable quantity in C or Rust can leak it's value by side-channels, e.g. power analysis.

Among the few uses of a variable quantity that is *generally*<sup>*</sup> safe from *timing* attack in compiled languages (like C or Rust) on modern CPUs are bitwise and arithmetic operators `& | ^ ~ + -` when operating on integer types; casting among these types; shift (`<< >>`) of such quantity if the shift count is non-secret (including a public constant shift). Also, reading from or writing to a variable (or a vector at a non-secret offset) is safe.

With this in mind, assuming `a` and `b` are of `unsigned` type, and `condition` is `0` or `1` and of type `ìnt`, this code is provably equivalent to the one in the question and is less unlikely to be constant-time:

```
unsigned ai = a ^ b;
unsigned bi = ((-(unsigned)conditional) & ai) ^ a; // b if conditional, a otherwise
ai ^= bi;                                          // a if conditional, b otherwise
f(ai, bi);
g(bi, ai);
```

This produces the correct result because `(-(unsigned)conditional)` has all it's bit at `0` if `conditional` is `0`, and all it's bit at `1` if `conditional` is `1`. This is an insurance of the C language.

This solves the data-dependent timing in the code shown, but is still potentially vulnerable to other side-channel attacks, e.g. power analysis. And of course there remains the potential for data-dependent timing inside the code of `f` and `g`.

---

<sup>*</sup> It's still advisable to check the generated code, especially when using signed quantities. An example is `uint64_t j = i` where `i` is an `ìnt8_t` variable: duration conceivably could depend on the sign of `i` on some combinations of CPU and compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
f(conditional ? a : b, conditional ? b : a)
g(conditional ? b : a, conditional ? a : b)
```

Then check the assembler code to see that the compiler is using conditional instruction.

Comment: I compiled [this](https://tio.run/##dY1NDoMgEIX3nOItMdEL2EXPMoCSSZohreKm8ewILAxtdFZf3s88O3hrU9oCO8w6ysJeJofY4@Ste6jq@3tfsaxY3pE@ky5ogzheOQi9miQ1bDp8FfLNugnjCcII0@NXNFmkvFMKXl94/4X6JRf2lA4) code [there](https://godbolt.org/) with their default (x86-64 gcc 13.2) and there are four more `jmp` when `conditional` is true. Curse is that the four tests are implemented with `je`. And even if nominal timing was the same, there could still be timing dependencies due to branch prediction. The safe thing is to consider that any code that branches according to secret data can leak it thru timing.

Comment: That’s a shame. Clang on arm which I usually use would do this without branches with a bit of optimisation. I guess gcc and clang should provide a built in intrinsic. You’d still have to check the assembler code.

Comment: This code would probably (I think, but not sure) compile to branch-free code on GPUs. I'd assume so as OpenCL spec specified a tenary operator-like function that's recommended as replacement for use in expressions in place of if-else statements

Comment: Admittedly, if I compile with -O2, gcc's code uses a single branch, and clang's code is linear. The later uses cmove, and I wish I knew if it is constant time on every x64 CPU.